# writing files to be imported as EMF models into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, emf

I'd like to generate an Eclipse EMF model in a custom tool (entirely outside of eclipse) and then save it to a format that eclipse can import and use as an EMF model.  I'm looking for recommendations of what format might be a good candiate.  It would be great if the format could be of a type can is stored in a text file and is (fairly) humon-readable. Also it would be good if there was, in some sense, a grammar available for the format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

GenMyModel is an online modeler, released as a beta version, that corresponds perfectly to your need. You can freely test it at http://www.genmymodel.com.

GenMyModel allows you to create class models and diagrams and to export them as Ecore files (relying on XMI, a standard for exchanging metadata information, by the OMG).

Comment: Actually - it was more that I have a similar piece of software - I'm just trying to write the export function in the most useful way possible... :s